# In a Wimshurst machine, why are the Leyden jars connected?

Tags: electrostatics

I generally understand how [Wimshurst machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wimshurst_machine) and [Leyden jars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leyden_jar) work, but I can't figure out why the outside of the two Leyden jars in a Wimshurst machine are connected to each other. The [DIY guide](http://cdn.instructables.com/F5Z/JIXZ/HYO8HXZS/F5ZJIXZHYO8HXZS.LARGE.jpg) I've been looking at has them connected. Wouldn't that result in the transfer of charge? However, as seen at about :30 in this [video](http://video.mit.edu/watch/dissectible-capacitor-3540/), when the two are not connected, no sparks are generated. Sorry if it's a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wimshurst machine deposits plus-charges in the inside of one Leyden jar, and minus-charges in the inside of the other Leyden jar.

The Wimshurst machine does not deposit anything in the outsides of the Leyden jars, but a charge difference is induced to the outsides of the jars, when the outsides are connected. Those induced charges in the outsides of the jars allow the Wimshurst machine to deposit more charges in the insides of the jars.